# Object existing after release

Tags: objective-c

Can anyone explain to me why class object still exist after release. Here is the code

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "MyClass.h"
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    MyClass *class = [[MyClass alloc] init];

    NSLog(@"%@", [class showMouse]);
    NSLog(@"%@", [class printKbd]);

    [class release];

    NSLog(@"%@", [class printKbd]);
    //still exist

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you call `release` object you only tell to it that it's not needful anymore. It will be released in some time later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, dealloc *does* get called, you can check it by adding `NSLog(@"dealloc called")` inside `dealloc` method of `MyClass`.

Why does it still work then? When an object gets released, the memory is not zeroed, it's simply marked as free to use by system. As a result, the code may still exist at the address of the pointer and `*class` is simply a pointer to a block of memory. [Here's the great SO answer that explains it in details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope).

Important thing to note is, should the program execution last any longer, the call to `[class printKbd]` would most likely crash. That's why it's important to assign `nil` to pointer, just to make sure we won't access the undefined part of memory.