# I was able to access object variable even after release method is called ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
 Profile *myProfile= [[Profile alloc]init];

[myProfile setName:@"Jhon Applesead"];
[myProfile setCompany:@"Apple"];

[myProfile release];

NSLog(@"Name is %@", [myProfile name]);
```

Log is

2013-02-28 15:41:36.866 Practice[8124:303] Name is Jhon Applesead

Comment: same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764330/object-existing-after-release

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope

Answer (score 3):

When you send a `release` message on an object, the object is actually **not being removed from the memory**. The release message simply **decrements the reference count by one** only. If the reference count is zero the object is marked as free. Then the system remove it from the memory. Until this deallocation happens you can access your object. Even if you `release` the object your object **pointer still points to the object** unless you are assigning `nil` to the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

I Think that's because you didn't release `name` and `company` inside the `dealloc` of `Profile`

Answer (score 1):

**release** does not necessarily destroy objects. It simply decrements the retain count by one. And if that retain count ever gets to zero, only then the object is **deallocated**. So this code works because a release happens but without triggering a **dealloc**.

For more details, see Apple's [memory management guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html).